# Is there a function to determine if a certain character is found within a c-string?

Tags: c++

I want to determine when the end of a sentence is, by using file streams and checking the data word by word. The only character that denotes the end of a sentence in this project is a `period .`.

I am looking for a function for `C++` to determine if a period is found within a certain word.

I've tried using the string find function but honestly cannot figure out what the return type is and how to structure the function, even after looking at references online.

Comment: What's unclear about the explanations [found here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should add your attempts and give examples for desired input/output.

Comment: The return type of string's `find()` functions is an unsigned integral type.   The returned value is the index of the character (or substring) if found, and `string::npos` (equal to the largest possible value the return type can hold) if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You the member function `std::string::find` just pass to it the period `.` and it returns for you the position if found:

```
std::string sText{ "I've tried using the string find function but honestly cannot figure out what the return type is and how to structure the function, even after looking at references online." };
std::string::size_type n{ sText.find('^') };
if (n != std::string::npos)
    cout << "found at: " << n << endl;
else
    cout << "Not found!" << endl;
```

- If you have to use const character strings then you can use `strchr`:

  ```
  const char *str = "I've tried using the string find function but honestly cannot figure out what the return type is and how to structure the function, even after looking at references online.";
  char target = '.';
  const char *result{ str };
  result = std::strchr(result, target);
  if (result)
      cout << "found at: " << result - str << endl;
  else
      cout << "Not found!" << endl;
  ```

Comment: Why do you do a `while` loop with `stdchr`? Can `strchr` return a valid pointer that after dereferencing is not equal to the second argument?